# Modificar metodo de Ordenamiento Quicksort

Tags: java, ordenamiento, quicksort, modificaciones

Necesito ayuda para modificar la implementacion de los metodos publicos y privados  de ordenamiento Quicksort  para que utilice el metodo privado mediana  como pivot. Hasta ahora tengo el metodo privado mediana agradeceria mucho si me ayudan con el resto
Por si acaso no me entienden les dejo el enunciado del ejercicio en cuestion

**Dentro de la clase Ordenamiento.java, escriba una función privada que permita
recibir 3 variables enteras y retorne la mediana de ellas. La mediana es el número
que está en la mitad de la lista, si la lista está ordenada.
6. Modifique esta implementación de QuickSort de la clase Ordenamiento.java para que
utilice la mediana de 3 como pivot. Debe utilizar la función creada en el ejercicio
previo, con los parámetros: primer elemento, último elemento y elemento de la
mitad del array desordenado.**

```
public class Ordenamiento {

    private int[] numbers;
    private int[] helper;
    private int number;

public void quickSort(int[] vector) {
        // Check for empty or null array
        if (vector == null || vector.length == 0) {
            return;
        }
        this.numbers = vector;
        number = vector.length;
        quicksort(0, number - 1);
    }

    private void quicksort(int low, int high) {
        int i = low, j = high;
        //Toma el pivot directamente de la mitad de la lista
        //Como ejercicio propuesto, queda que adapte el codigo para que use la mediana de tres
        int pivot = numbers[low + (high - low) / 2];

        // Divide into two lists
        while (i <= j) {
            // If the current value from the left list is smaller then the pivot
            // element then get the next element from the left list
            while (numbers[i] < pivot) {
                i++;
            }
            // If the current value from the right list is larger then the pivot
            // element then get the next element from the right list
            while (numbers[j] > pivot) {
                j--;
            }

            // If we have found a values in the left list which is larger then
            // the pivot element and if we have found a value in the right list
            // which is smaller then the pivot element then we exchange the
            // values.
            // As we are done we can increase i and j
            if (i <= j) {
                exchange(i, j);
                i++;
                j--;
            }
        }
        // Recursion
        if (low < j) {
            quicksort(low, j);
        }
        if (i < high) {
            quicksort(i, high);
        }
    }
    private int mediana(int primer, int mitad, int ultimo){
   int aux;
    int a=primer, b=mitad, c=ultimo;
    
        if(a>b) {
            if(a>c) {
                if(b>c) {
                
                primer=c;
                mitad=b;
                ultimo=a;           
                }else {
                primer=a;
                mitad=c;
                ultimo=b;
                }
            }else {
                primer=b;
                mitad=a;
                ultimo=c;
            }
        }else {
            if(b>c) {
                if(a>c) {
                primer=c;
                mitad=a;
                ultimo=b;
                    
                }else {
                primer=a;
                mitad=c;
                ultimo=b;
                    
                }              
            }else {
                primer=a;
                mitad=b;
                ultimo=c;
            }
        }
    return mitad;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero que necesitas es optimizar la función `mediana`. Tienes creada un montón de líneas de código que pueden simplificarse notablemente. Como bien se menciona, la `mediana` *es el valor intermedio entre los tres números de la entrada*, por tanto:

- Si el *primer número es mayor que el segundo* y *el primer número es mayor que el último*, entonces **la mediana es el primer número**.
- Si el *segundo número es mayor que el primero* y *el segundo número es mayor que el último*, entonces **la mediana es el segundo número**.
- Si no se cumple ninguno de los anteriores, **la mediana es el tercer número**.

Esto traducido a código, quedaría:

```
 private int mediana(int primer, int mitad, int ultimo) {
        if (primer >= mitad && primer <= ultimo) {
            return primer;
        } else if (mitad >= primer && mitad <= ultimo) {
            return mitad;
        } else {
            return ultimo;
        }
    }
```

La mediana en `quicksort` se usa para optimizar la selección del pivote. En la implementación que adjuntas, seleccionas el pivote siempre tomando el valor del centro del `array`. Esto puede mejorarse utilizando la `mediana` para seleccionar un mejor pivote.

La idea es considerar 3 candidatos a pivotes:

1. El elemento del inicio de la lista: `numbers[low]`
2. El elemento del centro de la lista: `numbers[center]`
3. El último elemento de la lista:  `numbers[high]`

La `mediana` entre estos tres elementos será el mejor pivote para el ordenamiento y el que dará un mejor desempeño. Calculamos entonces el mejor pivote usando la función implementada como:

```
 int center = low + (high - low) / 2;
 int pivot = mediana( numbers[low], numbers[center], numbers[high]);
```

Con esta pequeña modificación ya tienes la `mediana` adaptada al algoritmo. Tu clase `Ordenamiento` de manera íntegra se vería:

```
public class Ordenamiento {
    private int[] numbers;
    private int[] helper;
    private int number;

    public void quickSort(int[] vector) {
        // Check for empty or null array
        if (vector == null || vector.length == 0) {
            return;
        }
        this.numbers = vector;
        number = vector.length;
        quicksort( 0, number - 1 );
    }

    private void quicksort(int low, int high) {
        int i = low, j = high;
        // Código adaptado para que use la mediana de tres
        int center = low + (high - low) / 2;
        int pivot = mediana( numbers[low], numbers[center], numbers[high]);

        // Divide into two lists
        while (i <= j) {
            // If the current value from the left list is smaller then the pivot
            // element then get the next element from the left list
            while (numbers[i] < pivot) {
                i++;
            }
            // If the current value from the right list is larger then the pivot
            // element then get the next element from the right list
            while (numbers[j] > pivot) {
                j--;
            }

            // If we have found a values in the left list which is larger then
            // the pivot element and if we have found a value in the right list
            // which is smaller then the pivot element then we exchange the
            // values.
            // As we are done we can increase i and j
            if (i <= j) {
                exchange( i, j );
                i++;
                j--;
            }
        }
        // Recursion
        if (low < j) {
            quicksort( low, j );
        }
        if (i < high) {
            quicksort( i, high );
        }
    }

    private void exchange(int i, int j) {
        int temp = this.numbers[i];
        this.numbers[i] = this.numbers[j];
        this.numbers[j] = temp;
    }

    private int mediana(int primer, int mitad, int ultimo) {
        if (primer >= mitad && primer <= ultimo) {
            return primer;
        } else if (mitad >= primer && mitad <= ultimo) {
            return mitad;
        } else {
            return ultimo;
        }
    }
}
```

Como última observación cabe notar, que usualmente las implementaciones con la `mediana` lo que hacen es modificar el `array` original tomando el primer elemento, el del centro y el último y los colocan en orden. Es decir, al inicio ponen el menor de los 3, al final ponen el mayor de los 3, y en el medio pues la mediana. De esta manera siempre están tomando como pivote el elemento del centro, pero como hacen estas modificaciones antes, siempre están asegurándose que en el medio esté la `mediana`. Dado que la orden del ejercicio decía de manera explícita las instrucciones para la función mediana, descarté esta forma de hacerlo, pero es la que te encontrarás en muchos lugares.